# Display an image from datagridview to a picturebox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Can anyone help me with this one? The scenario is that when I click any columns in a datagridview it will display the image to a picturebox

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        lblProperty.Text = row.Cells("Column1").Value.ToString
        txtType.Text = row.Cells("Column2").Value.ToString
        txtPrice.Text = row.Cells("Column3").Value.ToString
        txtBed.Text = row.Cells("Column4").Value.ToString
        txtBath.Text = row.Cells("Column5").Value.ToString
        txtFootages.Text = row.Cells("Column6").Value.ToString
        txtStatus.Text = row.Cells("Column7").Value.ToString
        txtYear.Text = row.Cells("Column8").Value.ToString
        txtDesc.Text = row.Cells("Column9").Value.ToString

        Dim bytes As [Byte]() = row.Cells("Column10").Value
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        pbImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

        txtDate.Text = row.Cells("Column11").Value.ToString
        txtAddress.Text = row.Cells("Column12").Value.ToString
        txtStories.Text = row.Cells("Column13").Value.ToString

    End If
End Sub
```

It has an error Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

Comment: It's evident you are not storing the pictures byte array in that cell, rather a string... Is it a path to the picture?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = Datagridview1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
Picturebox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
End Using
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please try to add some notes on your code rather than just pasting code.  I have re-formatted the code for you to aid readability

Comment: @OldBoyCoder  I think the code is pretty much clear and working now.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are over thinking it, there is a function to easily draw bitmaps.

I would suggest using the DrawToBitmap on the DataGridView by using the ColumnBounds
example this:

```
Dim GridBitmap as new Bitmap(DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(row.Cells("Column10").ColumnIndex,false).width,DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(row.Cells("Column10").ColumnIndex,false).height)
DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(GridBitmap,DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(row.Cells("Column10").ColumnIndex,false))
pbImage.Image = GridBitmap
```

It might need to be adapted to your DataGridView.

Note, Instead of this:

> ```
>     Dim bytes As [Byte]() = row.Cells("Column10").Value
>     Dim ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
>     pbImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
> ```

Still having problem? Try this:

New project.
Add a DataGridView (DataGridView1) to your form.
Add some random columns to your gridview.
Add a Picture Box to your form (PictureBox1)
Make sure the Picture box property "SizeMode" is set to auto size.
Add an event forDataGridView1.MouseDown.
Add this code to the event.

```
Dim GridBitmap As New Bitmap(DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, True).Width + DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, True).Left, DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, True).Height)
Dim GridColRectangle As New Rectangle(0, 0, DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, True).Width + DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, True).Left, DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, True).Height + DataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, True).Top)
DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(GridBitmap, GridColRectangle)
PictureBox1.Image = GridBitmap
```

You may need to adjust it to your own application.

Comment: It is still not working, it has an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Comment: I've updated the answer, try the sample code in a new project.